# Errors in my code

Tags: class, function, lookup, matching, member

Alright, I have a couple error messages and I am stuck. Just seeing if anybody could help me out here, it would be greatly appreciated.

**Here is the error message:**

bibleajax.cpp: In function âint main():

bibleajax.cpp:92: error: no matching function for call to Bible::lookup(Verse&, LookupResult&)

Bible.h:32: note: candidates are: const Verse Bible::lookup(Ref, LookupResult&)
make: *** [bibleajax.o] Error 1

**Here is line 92:**

```
Ref nRef;
    Verse nVerse;

    for (int t = 0; t < num; t++){
        do {
            nRef = kjv.lookup(nVerse, result);
            nVerse = kjv.lookup(nRef, result);
           }
        while (result != ch && result != no_chapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that your `Verse` class does not have a member function called `getRef()`. You also appear to be trying to call the `lookup` function by passing it a `Verse` object instead of a `Ref` object... but that piece of code doesn't seem to be included in what you've posted here.

Note that the relevant line numbers for the code are posted in the error messages. So check lines 79 and 92 for the issues I mentioned here.

Comment: You shouldn't paste it here as a comment. Perhaps add it to your original question. And likely it's the .h file, not the .cpp file that we're interested in.

Comment: Alright, I implemented that in, created Ref getRef(); in my Verse.h. That corrected my first error. Still cannot get the Bible.h fix though. I'll post that now.

Comment: @Trent Please post the area around line 92 of bibleajax.cpp. Bible.h itself does not have an error: notice how it says "note:". It's telling you *why* line 92 of bibleajax.cpp is an error. You're passing one type of argument to a function that requires a different type of argument. It appears as if on line 92 you're passing it a `Verse` object when you need to pass it a `Ref` object.

Comment: My bad man, sorry for making this so difficult. I just re-read the error message and noticed that myself. I'll repost it yet again.

Comment: Ok, well I just noticed I was passing it cVerse instead of nVerse, but that still didn't fix the error.

Comment: @Trent Notice that you're making *two* calls to `kjv.lookup()`. In the first, you're correctly passing it a `Verse` object named `nVerse`. That line is not a problem. Immediately below, however, you call the lookup function and pass it a `Ref` object named `nRef`. You have **not** defined a function called lookup that accepts an argument of type `Ref`, so this is an error. Either define what the function `lookup` is supposed to do when it receives a `Ref` object or remove that line entirely.